# Error when displaying the map using Skobbler in Android

Tags: android, opengl-es, maps, skmaps

I want to integrate a map in my android application. But I'm just starting form the basics and I'm already encountering a crash/error.

I just copied some codes from the demo project but still no luck.

**Logcat :**

```
08-14 16:19:55.703: E/AndroidRuntime(30065): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 787
08-14 16:19:55.703: E/AndroidRuntime(30065): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-14 16:19:55.703: E/AndroidRuntime(30065):    at com.skobbler.ngx.map.MapRenderer.onSurfaceCreated(SourceFile:487)
08-14 16:19:55.703: E/AndroidRuntime(30065):    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1509)
08-14 16:19:55.703: E/AndroidRuntime(30065):    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1248)
```

I researched already but I haven;t found any solution yet. 
Please help.

Here's my code:
MainActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

SKLogging.enableLogs(true);
File externalDir = getExternalFilesDir(null);
if (externalDir != null) {`enter code here`
    mapresDirPath = externalDir + "/SKMaps/";
} else {
    mapresDirPath = getFilesDir() + "/SKMaps/";
}

if (!new File(mapresDirPath).exists()) {
    new SKPrepareMapTextureThread(this, mapresDirPath, "SKMaps.zip", this).start();
    copyOtherResources();
    prepareMapCreatorFile();
 } else {
 Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Map resources copied in a previous run", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 prepareMapCreatorFile();
        initializeLibrary();
        finish();
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MapActivity.class));
    }



}

private void initializeLibrary() {
    SKMapsInitSettings initSettings = new SKMapsInitSettings();
    initSettings.setMapResourcesPaths(mapresDirPath, new SKMapViewStyle(mapresDirPath + "daystyle/", "daystyle.json"));

    final SKAdvisorSettings advisorSettings = initSettings.getAdvisorSettings();
    advisorSettings.setLanguage("en");
    advisorSettings.setAdvisorVoice("en");
    advisorSettings.setPlayInitialAdvice(true);
    advisorSettings.setPlayAfterTurnInformalAdvice(true);
    advisorSettings.setPlayInitialVoiceNoRouteAdvice(true);
    initSettings.setAdvisorSettings(advisorSettings);

    SKVersioningManager.getInstance().setMapUpdateListener(this);
    SKMaps.getInstance().initializeSKMaps(this, initSettings, API_KEY);
}

@Override
public void onMapTexturesPrepared(boolean prepared) {
    initializeLibrary();
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Map resources were copied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            finish();
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MapActivity.class));
        }
    });
}
```

MapActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);

    SKMapViewHolder mapViewHolder = (SKMapViewHolder) findViewById(R.id.map_surface_holder);
    mapView = mapViewHolder.getMapSurfaceView();

    mapView.getMapSettings().setMapPanningEnabled(true);
    mapView.getMapSettings().setMapZoomingEnabled(true);
    mapView.getMapSettings().setInertiaPanningEnabled(true);


    SKVersioningManager.getInstance().setMapUpdateListener(this);
}
```

Comment: check this line at com.skobbler.ngx.map.MapRenderer.onSurfaceCreated(SourceFile:487)

Comment: this is code form SKMaps.jar which I don;t have access since I only use their library. Could you help me?

Comment: post your code and notify line 487

Comment: I edited my roiginal post for the code

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and I posted an answer on their support forum :

> Hi,
>
> Implementing Skobbler in my android app, I stucked half an hour with a crash I couldn't understand.
>   Following the DemoApp for the initialization part, I kept crashing just before map was displayed with error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.skobbler.ngx.map.MapRenderer.onSurfaceCreated( SourceFile:487)
    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(G LSurfaceView.java:1509)
    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfac eView.java:1248)
```

> As the error wasn't self explanatory at all, I investigated file MapRenderer from package com.skobbler.ngx.map, and found
>   that I was crashing because I didn't implement a map listener (this.s, in line below), which classname was trying to be displayed on log.

```
public final void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 arg1, EGLConfig paramEGLConfig)
{
    SKLogging.writeLog("MapRenderer", "onSurfaceCreated before LOCK ", 2);
    synchronized (V) {
        SKLogging.writeLog("MapRenderer", "onSurfaceCreated" + this.s.getClass().getName(), 2); // <== Line 487
```

> You might have forgot to check non-nullity of this.s before logging it, and as it wasn't described as mandatory in your doc to
>   implement this listener,I think you should correct that, or otherwise precise it in documentation.

http://forum.skobbler.com/showthread.php/6554-Android-Resolution-for-NullPointerException-onSurfaceCreated(SourceFile-487)?p=17601#post17601

Hope that helps !

tl:dr :

```
SKMapSurfaceView mapView = mapViewContainer.getMapSurfaceView();
mapView.setMapSurfaceListener(new SKMapSurfaceListener() {...});
```